# Suppress rsync warnings but not errors

Tags: command-line, rsync

I'm using `rsync` to transfer from one server to another using an account that has no home directory:

```
rsync user@server:source target
Password:
Could not chdir to home directory /dev/null: Not a directory
bash: /dev/null/.bashrc: Ist kein
Verzeichnis
```

As the `rsync` is successful, I'd consider that a **warning** message as opposed to an **error** message stating a reason why `rsync` **failed**.

Is there a (simple) way to tell `rsync` to **only** print errors if something actually **failed**?

Answer (score 1):

Arguably the `Could not chdir to home directory` message *is* an error.

It's not a function of `rsync` as can be seen in this similar scenario (`nohome` is an account I created that has no home directory):

```
ssh nohome@localhost date
nohome@localhost's password:
Could not chdir to home directory /dev/null: Not a directory
Thu  1 Aug 07:02:05 UTC 2019
```

I can't find a way to suppress that message (`ssh -q` and `rsync -q` both have no relevant effect).

With regard to `rsync`, it doesn't even see that message. The exit status from `rsync` is SUCCESS (0) if all items are successfully transferred - regardless of the lack of home directory:

```
touch /tmp/x
rsync -av nohome@localhost:/tmp/x /tmp/y; echo Status=$?
nohome@localhost's password:
Could not chdir to home directory /dev/null: Not a directory
receiving incremental file list
x

sent 43 bytes  received 83 bytes  50.40 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
Status=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've just found a solution myself:

```
if ! output=$(rsync user@server:source target 2>&1); then
  echo "$output"
fi
```

The output (stdout and stderr) is saved in a variable which is only printed, if the exit code is not 0.

Not sure if there's a better way, but this definitely works for me.

**Background**

The user is in fact a machine account and the actual `rsync` is called via a wrapper script that accepts a file (`/etc/machine.secret`) as a password. The script itself is run via `cron` so I had to find a way to get mails if and only if something goes wrong.

Not doing anything means I get that "error" mail every time the script is called, doing a rather simple `2>/dev/null` means I don't get any error mails at all, so I had to find a way to filter out that specific message.

Comment: As I explained in [my own answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/533328/100397), the "No home directory" error isn't seen as an error from by `rsync` so the exit status that you're testing is unaffected by this message.

Comment: @roaima Yep, that's better. Thanks for pointing it out. I corrected it. I know that rsync doesn't see it as an error (despite sending it to stderr) and frankly, I'm glad it doesn't. I'll add some background to understand why I'm doing what I'm doing...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the `-q` switch ? It suppresses non-error messages.

`rsync -q user@server:source target`

Comment: Did you try this? It doesn't affect errors from the `ssh` login (and nor does adding `-e 'ssh -q'`).

Comment: Why do you downvote ? He didn't talk about SSH... The question is : "Is there a (simple) way to tell rsync to only print errors if something actually failed?"

Comment: I downvoted because your answer doesn't work. I mentioned `ssh` because the `rsync` command you suggested uses `ssh` to provide the transport layer for `rsync`.